Issues with Mono.data.sqlite in .NET 8 MAUI (Sqlite3 dll not found exception)
I’m currently working on a .NET MAUI 8 project and have encountered an issue with Mono.Data.Sqlite. The sqlite3.dll file seems to be missing or not properly loaded, leading to the following error:
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found.
I am using the package below for the SQLite connection,
To resolve this, I’m exploring alternative database solutions that offer similar functionality to Mono.Data.Sqlite.Are compatible with .NET MAUI
Resolving SQLite3 Issues: If anyone has experienced this error, how did you resolve it? Are there specific configurations or steps that I might have missed?
Alternative Databases: What database solutions do you recommend for .NET MAUI projects?

please read the docs on using SQLIte with MAUI
